# Adding Google Play Game Services to existing app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

We already have a app/game published under App All apps list as a normal app and now we want to add Play game service login to let users save game progress.

After going through the documentations we have learned that we will need to setup `Play Game Services` under the app where we are required to add credentials and publish the game. So our concern is will it create a new app on the playstore or it will be published in Google Games only?

what is the correct way to add Play game login in existing app which is already published?

Answer (score 0):

See [Setting Up Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).

At step 2 choose: "Yes, my game already uses Google APIs".

It needs these dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:21.0.0"
```

As well as `res/values/ids.xml` (from the Google Play Console) and  `AndroidManifest.xml` edited:

```
<application
    ...>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    ...

</application>
```

It's also explained explained [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_3_modify_your_code).

Comment: I have done everything but still i am getting this error when using snapshot "Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console" I have checked multiple times that saved Game option is enabled on console.